# What are the different ways I can export permissions from a preconfigured Drupal site

Tags: 7, users

I have a site that I need to export permissions from and import into version-controlled code. We aren't using feature, strongarm etc, so although I know a  lot of people will say these are the go to  solutions, I need to look at alternatives. Are permissions stored as variables in the site or otherwise? I would I export and import variables into an install profile or in a module?

Comment: Anything wrong with simply exporting `{role_permission}` table? If your roles id are not supposed to change, it should be all you really need, but I guess for some reason you need a solution a bit more advanced?

Comment: Why aren't you using features? I'll be glad to know the reason. My team and I were using features and it works like a charm..

Comment: I don't really know apart from its bloat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module[(Export roles and permissions)](https://drupal.org/project/export_roles_permissions) allows you to exports roles and permission by generating a hook_install implementation

> This module allows you to generate a hook_install() implementation
>   that creates the chosen roles with their associated permissions. The
>   main purpose for creating this module was to transfer roles from a
>   local dev machine to a remote stage/live server.

Comment: that looks the business.